# How to change GreyScale images to Colored variants?

Tags: android, colors, imageview, grayscale

I'm working on a little side-project that uses images with only grey-hues and no colors. I was wondering if it's possible to throw something like an opaque (is that the right word?) 'filter' or 'layer' over these images to color them according to the strenght of the Grey color.
Say I want the images to be blue, do I get the pixel-data and up the 'B', or is there an easyer way?

Basically what it boils down to is this: Everytime the app starts, a different color is selected (Orange, Blue, Green, Pink, etc.) and thrown over the grey images. But how does one achieve this?

-Zubaja

Comment: Use a ColorFilter. Tutorial:http://android-er.blogspot.it/2012/09/example-to-apply-colorfilter-on.html

Comment: @DerGolem Oh, Shiny matrices and math. I missed that! Thanks, checking it out now!

Comment: It's much faster than changing color values pixel by pixel.

Comment: I admit my defeat :)

Comment: Did you solve your problem yet?

Comment: @Suragch I haven't tried the mentioned solutions yet, as I have had 0 time to try them out, even during the weekend. I'll update ASAP. Trying to get Android SDK in Eclipse to work at work now.

Comment: @Suragch Got it to work at work, but now Eclipse can't find my device. I'll try it at home tonight; I should have some time available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @DerGolem mentioned above, if you want to do it programmatically, it looks like one of these tutorials could help you solve your problem:

- [Example to apply ColorFilter on ImageView](http://android-er.blogspot.it/2012/09/example-to-apply-colorfilter-on.html)
- [Swap color using ColorFilter](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2012/09/swap-color-using-colorfilter.html)

However, there might be an easier way. I haven't tried this myself, but this is what I would do:

In Gimp, or some other photo editor, convert the grey in your images to alpha (transparent). Then put your image in an `ImageView` in a `FrameLayout`. At runtime you can programmatically set the background color of the FrameLayout. Whatever color you set should show through the transparent areas of your image, making it look as if you changed the image color.

Comment: I've used the code from your first example and it works! I'm going to fiddle with it a bit to see what's possible. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score -1):

You'll have to **apply it pixel by pixel**.Pretty much like you already mentioned.Look here for inspiration:

[Image Editing Filters Tutorials](http://xjaphx.wordpress.com/learning/tutorials/)

Scroll down to "Android: Image Processing"

Comment: Thank you. I will check this at home, as my computer at work isn´t recognising my device at the moment.